# Clearcase [not loaded]

Tags: clearcase

When I execute a "cleartool ls filename@@specificVersion", I see

`filename [not loaded]`

What does this mean?

For background information, I was trying to also execute a `cleartool mkbranch`, and was a "Element not found" error. So, for a sanity check, I tried a cleartool ls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`not loaded`" means the file:

- is selected (by the selection rules element * ...) but:
- not loaded by the load rules (load /xx/yy...)

You can see both sets of rules by doing a `cleartool catcs` anywhere within your view (or `cleartool edcs` to edit said rules)

This is typical of a snapshot view, which is the only one having "load rules" (as opposed to a dynamic view)

See:

- "[Before accessing files not loaded into snapshot views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/before_access_not_load_ssv.htm)":

> A snapshot view contains only the set of elements that you specify in the load rules of your view. (In UCM, by default, your view loads all of your project source files.)
>
> **When you restrict the scope of a view, it contains only a subset of elements in the VOB**. During the course of a development cycle, you may need to see a version of an element that is not loaded into your snapshot view.
>
> You can view nonloaded files or copy them into your view for build purposes, but you cannot check them out. Only file elements that are loaded into your view can be checked out.

- "[To copy a nonloaded element into a snapshot view](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_copy_nonload_ssv.htm)"

  ```
  cleartool get -to filename path
  cleartool get -to prog.c.previous.version prog.c@@/main/v3.1_fix/10
  ```